# SQL Server Money gives wrong values when calculated back

Tags: sql-server, currency

It seems Money has a fixed precision and always have 4 decimals. This causes me problems cause lets say I have a table of items to sell, like below

```
create table #example (
   id int,
   name varchar(50),
   price money
)
```

If the money column in #example is the price before VAT and VAT value is 8%, 4 decimals might not be enough. In below example I'm using an item price of 11usd (before vat)

```
insert into #example (id, name, price) values (1, 'asd', 11/1.08)
```

A select from #example now gives:

```
id  name price
1   asd 10,1852
```

If I want to use this price to add the vat value I get the wrong value:

```
10.1852*1,08 = 11,000016
```

This leaves a wrong margin of 0,000016USD. Obviously I'm using it wrong. Anyone have any input on where I'm wrong on this?

Edit:
I wouldn't say the attached question has my answer. I'm already certain to use money and I just need help on calculating the values back.

Comment: I ran that query in SQL2012 and got the correct answer - 10.185 both using "(11/1.08)" and using simply "11/1.08", so you might check the version and see if there's an issue related to the versioning.

Comment: I'm running this on 2012 aswell, but I don't get why 10.185 is right? 10.185*1,08 is 10,9998. I'm prob missing something, I just don't know what :)

Comment: This what my code:

insert into _testmoney
values (2,'dog',11/1.08)

select * from _testmoney